Python help: I have a exe file that takes two arguments and generates an output I would like to run a script that calls the exe file hundreds of times
I have an executable file that works like this:
a.exe arg1 arg2
It generates an output: abc.
I would like to write a python script that runs a.exe in a loop and stores the output for each execution either in an excel file or an array that I can later export to an excel.
How would I get started?
I don't know how to run the exe file in a loop and store multiple arguments


You can execute the .exe file within python by using subprocess.
Here is the code sample for the same:

import subprocess
import pandas as pd

arg_list = [
    ("arg1_val1", "arg2_val1"),
    ("arg1_val2", "arg2_val2"),
    # ..... so on
]

output_list = []

for args in arg_list:
    result = subprocess.run(['a.exe', args[0], args[1]], capture_output=True, text=True)
    
    output_list.append([args[0], args[1], result.stdout.strip()])

df = pd.DataFrame(output_list, columns=["Arg1", "Arg2", "Output"])

df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)

print("Data saved to output.xlsx")

